# Where will it stop/come up to and which platform will it arrive on/come on

Tags: word-usage

My mother asked a person on a train station about a particular car of the train that we were going to board. (Actually in my country each car of the train is  named like 1A, 2A etc.) So she was actually asking where our train car would stop.

> Where will 2A **stop**?
>
> Where will 2A **come up to**?

Which one out of the two sounds better  "stop" or "come up to"? I mean what's more likely to be used? (The context is quite clear and the person my mom's talking to knows which train she's talking about)

---

And about a platform:

> Which platform will the train **come on**?
>
> Which platform will the train **arrive on**?

Which one sounds better "come on" or "arrive on "?

Answer (score 1):

"Where will 2A stop?" is correct and sounds best.

"Which platform will the train come on?" is not correct (or I hope not as your mom may be injured). Passengers are on the platform, not trains. "Which platform will the train arrive at? is the correct question.

> [platform](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/platform)
>   noun UK ​  /ˈplæt.fɔːm/ US ​  /ˈplæt.fɔːrm/
>   ​
>   a flat raised area or structure
>   ​
>   a long, flat raised structure at a railway station, where people get on and off trains:
>
> The next train for Aberdeen will depart from platform 9.